# Where can I find a good dataset for Customer Journey Analysis (Multi-Touch Attribution)?

Tags: data-science-model

For my thesis I need to find a dataset regarding customer journey analysis, hereby I assign credits to touchpoints of certain channels to see which channels are the most efficient. For example a customer sees a instagram ad, facebook ad and email ad. Eventueally the customer buys the product through the email ad but the instagram and facebook ad had a large impact on this that did not get measured. If i could get such a dataset it would be very cool. (A real life dataset too not synthetic) I have been looking for hours on kaggle, google dataset search and other mediums which unfortunately did not give the desired results if you know something please let me know Thank you!